# angularfire get the length of an object from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm stuck with this.
I'm using angularfire 2 in ionic 2 and I need to get length of an object that I get with :

```
this.userEmailAddress = this.af.database.object('/users/'+this.authInfo.uid+'/emailAddress')
```

How to know if the object exist of if it's null ?

Thanks.

Comment: is your question, how do i get the length of the string? What type are you expecting to be returned here?

Comment: I mean if the child 'emailAddress' exist and contains a string.